# Adobe Flex - mxmlc.exe and compile with dependent libraries

Tags: flex3, mxmlc

I have Flex SDK 4.6. I would like to work with library https://github.com/y8/websocket-as. This library needed library as3corelib (https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib). The problem is, that I'm not able to use/include this libraries in my HelloWorld project.

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.TextField;
import y8.net.WebSocket;

public class HelloWorld extends Sprite {

    public function HelloWorld() {
        var display_txt:TextField = new TextField();
        display_txt.text = "Hello World!";
        addChild(display_txt);
    }
}
}
```

When I compile it with *mxmlc.exe -o HelloWorld.swf tuts\HelloWorld.as*, I get error

> HelloWorld.as(5): col: 15 Error: Definition y8.net:WebSocket could not be found.
>
> ```
>    import y8.net.WebSocket;
> ```

Please, how can I put it together (directories) and how can I compile this libraries and HelloWordl with mxmlc.exe. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
mxmlc -library-path+=/myLibraries/MyRotateEffect.swc;/myLibraries/MyButtonSwc.swc c:/myFiles/app.mxml
```

ref: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=apparch_08.html